# Is there a key-binding to move the cursor to the last character in the buffer

Tags: key-bindings, shell

Is there a key binding that moves the cursor to the last character in a buffer? I'm asking because I often find myself at a point other than the last character, where I want to be, in the interactive-shell.

Comment: The `special-mode-map` uses `>` for buffers like the `*Help*` buffer.  [See `simple.el`.]  The `global-map` uses `C-end`.  [See `bindings.el`.]  The `esc-map` uses `>` -- the `esc` key is bound by default to the `Meta` key on the GUI version of Emacs by way of the `meta-prefix-char`.  [See `bindings.el`.]

Comment: For Emacs versions built `--with-ns` -- i.e., OSX -- the library `ns-win.el` sets up two additional ways to trigger `end-of-buffer` with keyboard shortcuts -- i.e., `end` and `kp-end`.  For example, I can type `fn+right` and go to the end of the buffer on my Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-end` (and `M->` and another in default) runs command `end-of-buffer` (into `simple.el`), which moves cursor to the end of the buffer.  With numeric argument, for example, `C-u 4 C-end`, moves point to 4/10 from the end of the accessable part.  With narrowed buffer moves point into the narrowed path of the buffer.

You could find all the keybindings for function with `C-h f end-of-buffer RET`.

Comment: Yup. So `M-> C-b` puts point at (before) the last character. ;-)

Comment: And `(goto-char (1- (point-max)))` do the same (puts point before the last character).